# How do I end a sentence with a quote mid-sentence?

Tags: word-usage, quotes

For example, if I wanted to say:

> John Muir says in his 5th paragraph, "I splashed on through the swamp,
>   strong and exhilarated(.) (. . .)"

Would I end the quote with a period since it is the end of my sentence, or would I use an ellipsis as I ended the quote mid-sentence?

Comment: I think square brackets are generally used for additions/removals inside quotes.

Comment: That depends on what style guide you are using. [See reference.](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html)

Comment: If you are asking if you can end with period quote, even though the original is mid-sentence, yes.

Comment: "I splashed on through the swamp, strong and exhilarated ...."  Note the space before the ellipse and the ending period.

Comment: @marcellothearcane My recollection is that square brackets are used to indicate changed text in a quote.  "[D]ave is a key prospect."

Comment: @marcellothearcane My apologies.  The MLA Handbook recommends surrounding ellipses with square brackets to differentiate omissions made by you from those already present in the quoted text.  [The Ellipses](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/ellipsis.htm). I didn't know that one. "I splashed on through the swamp, strong and exhilarated [...]."

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style. Authorities differ on the usage of ellipsis points when a quotation is placed at the end of a sentence, and the quoted material itself is only part of a larger sentence.

[*The Chicago Manual of Style*](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_sec050.html) omits the ellipsis in favour of a sentence-ending period:

> John Muir says in his 5th paragraph, "I splashed on through the swamp,
>   strong and exhilarated."

[Note, however, [an exception](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_sec053.html) in the case where the sentence as quoted is deliberately incomplete.]

[*The MLA Handbook*](https://www.uhv.edu/student-success-center/resources/e-p/ellipsis-use-in-mla-style/) places the sentence-ending period after the last word of the quotation, and follows that with an ellipsis:

> John Muir says in his 5th paragraph, "I splashed on through the swamp,
>   strong and exhilarated. . . ."

[Regarding a comment made above regarding MLA style for ellipses, it appears that *The MLA Handbook* dictates that ellipses be enclosed in square brackets only when it is necessary to distinguish these from ellipses in the original quoted text. Refer [here](https://www.uhv.edu/student-success-center/resources/e-p/ellipsis-use-in-mla-style/), scroll down to *Ellipses in Work that Includes Ellipsis*.]